# What happens if a character's velocity is greater than 0m when the character gets a Phase?

Tags: movement, hero-system

I'm preparing to run a *Hero System, 6th Edition* campaign, and I'm struggling to understand movement, especially velocity. Here's the question: **When a character's Phase ends yet his velocity is still greater than 0m, does the character's velocity affect what Actions the character can take on his next Phase?**

For example, Slick's Phase ends, but his velocity is still 20m. On Slick's next Phase, can he take a Zero Phase Action to add velocity (E61 156), spend a Half Phase to take a Half Move during which he adds even more velocity, then spend a Half Phase to take an Action that requires an Attack roll, despite Slick still having a greater-than-0m velocity? Or, because Slick's velocity is 20m at the start of the Phase, must Slick first take a Full Move or Half Move to reduce his velocity to 0m before the character can do anything else besides move?

---

***Note:** My confusion stems from this statement: A character "may not deactivate the Movement Power until he decelerates to 0m normally or through some outside means" (E61 156 and E62 25). So far as I can tell, the game doesn't describe exactly what this means (i.e. I can't tell if not moving is supposed to be the same thing as deactivating a Movement Power). Further, the game doesn't seem to describe how already having velocity when a Phase begins impacts the character's ability to take Actions. Finally, I've found no examples that cover what I imagine is this relatively common situation.*

Comment: I waited a day then also asked this on the Hero Games forum [here](https://www.herogames.com/forums/topic/100693-what-happens-if-a-characters-velocity-is-greater-than-0m-when-the-character-gets-a-phase/).